# Unique Customers Per Restaurant

Tags: sql

Been having trouble accomplishing the following query in SQL.

Say I have a table like this:

```
customerID | restaurant
-----------+-----------
1          | Taco Bell
1          | Taco Bell
1          | McDonald's
2          | Subway
2          | Subway
3          | Taco Bell
3          | Taco Bell
```

How would I output the total unique customers for each restaurant? I can't change this table's format by the way. It's the unique customer part that is messing me up.

Does anyone have any tips or guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)`:

```
select restaurant, count(distinct customerid)
from t
group by restaurant;
```